# php gnupg = unable to load warning

Tags: php, installation, lamp, gpg

End goal: use PHP GnuPG library in my Mediawiki extension

I have installed

- gpgme with dependencies
- run pecl install gnupg = no errors
- added extension=gnupg.so to my php.ini

:

```
[root@dev-lamp01]# locate gnupg.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/gnupg.so

[root@dev-lamp01]# file /usr/lib64/php/modules/gnupg.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/gnupg.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

[root@dev-lamp01]# locate  libgpgme.so.11
/usr/local/lib/libgpgme.so.11
/usr/local/lib/libgpgme.so.11.8.1

[root@dev-lamp01]# file /usr/local/lib/libgpgme.so.11
/usr/local/lib/libgpgme.so.11: symbolic link to `libgpgme.so.11.8.1'

[root@dev-lamp01]# file /usr/local/lib/libgpgme.so.11.8.1
/usr/local/lib/libgpgme.so.11.8.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

yet:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gnupg.so' - libgpgme.so.11: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

what am i missing? thanks

Comment: i ran 

[root@dev-lamp01 modules]# ldd /usr/lib64/php/modules/gnupg.so

        libgpgme.so.11 => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002aefb4964000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002aefb452e000)

Comment: updating LD_LIBRARY_PATH helped it for the php cli... - will restart httpd tonight to check how it helps for the web side of things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution that fixed the problem in my case:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(function_exists("gnupg_decrypt"));';

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/gnupg.so' - **libgpgme.so.11: cannot open shared object file**: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
bool(false)

$ ldd /usr/lib/php5/20100525/gnupg.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff715ff000)
    **libgpgme.so.11 => not found**
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f087c815000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f087cdea000)
```

It seems that the server doesn’t load libraries from the `/usr/local/lib` folder. To fix this problem just add `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` or/and run `ldconfig`.